# Finding even numbers with while as

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm doing this assignment:

> Write a program that prints all even numbers less than the input
>   number using the while loop.
>
> The input format:
>
> The maximum number N that varies from 1 to 200.
>
> The output format:
>
> All even numbers less than N in ascending order. Each number must be
>   on a separate line.

```
N = int(input())
i = 0
while 200 >= N >= 1:
    i += 1
    if i % 2 == 0 and N > i:
        print(i)
```

and its output like:

```
10  # this is my input
2
4
6
8
```

but there is an error about time exceed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you show us the error?

Comment: You don't need to test each number. Start with 0 or 2 (which ever is the smallest allowable number), and increment *by* 2 on each iteration. Do that, and you can't generate an odd number in the first place.

Comment: Your loop is not stopping since you don't modify anything that appears in your condition. But as soon as N=i, you could stop looping. Do you see how you could change your condition to solve it?

Comment: Also, your `while` loop will never end since your condition doesn't check the value of `i`.

Comment: I don't know how i can stop the loop,

N = int(input())
i = 2
while 200 >= N >= 1:
    if i % 2 == 0 and N > i:
        print(i)
        i += 2

this time i printed like that, when i run this it's okay but when i submit my code for solving the problem it gives accurately "Time limit exceeded" error... I'm so confused... I'm thinking about whether I am dumb... I think i should improve my logic...

Answer (score 1):

The simple code would be:

```
import math

N = int(input(""))
print("1. " + str(N))

num = 1

while num < math.ceil(N/2):
    print (str(num) + ". " + str(num * 2))
    num += 1
```

Comment: @Hasan Cem PINAR You might have forgotten to change the counter, in this case 'i', so you got into a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the while loop never stops

`while 200 >= N >= 1` In this case because you never change the value of N the condition will always be true. Maybe you can do something more like this:

```
N = int(input())
if N > 0 and N <= 200:
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        i += 2
        print(i)
else 
    print("The input can only be a number from 1 to 200")
```

Comment: Because the numbers can go from 1 to 200. So i use the if to check f the input is valid @Onyambu

Comment: @Onyambu The problem statement says that `N` can only be between 1 and 200. The error check is valid.

Comment: @Onyambu OP does not want if input 100 output even numbers from 2 - 200, the input and output format are very clear. The if is checking if the input format is correct and the else gives an error message in case the input is invalid